# Image внутри блока с отступом, на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

Есть такое:

```css
.wrap{margin:0 40px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="images/img.png">
  <div>
    различные элементы
  </div>
  <img src="images/img.png">
  <div>
    различные элементы
  </div>
</div>`
```

Как растянуть картинку на ширину экрана, не меняя код?
У картинок не должно быть отступа вообще, они должны растягиваться до краев экрана по всей ширине, а у wrap отступ должен остаться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать относительные единицы **vw**.

```css
.wrap{margin:0 40px;}

img {
    width: 100vw;
    min-width: 100vw;
    margin:0 -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x50/green/">
  <div>
    различные элементы
  </div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x50/green/">
  <div>
    различные элементы
  </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете задать ширину в 100vw (ширина всего вьюпорт, viewport)

```css
body {
/*что бы было нагляднее, сбросил стандартные отступы браузера*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-right: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 0 40px;" class="wrap"> //margin:0 40px;
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x50/green/">
    <div>
       различные элементы
    </div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x150/red/">
    <div>
       различные элементы
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я наверное не правильно выразился. У картинок не должно быть отступа вообще, они должны растягиваться до краев экрана по всей ширине, а у wrap отступ должен остаться

Comment: Код поправил, изменил ширину с 100%  на 100vw